# Generate rows based to make a sequence in a column of a dataframe

Tags: for-loop, while-loop, append, row

I'm trying to generate new rows based on values in a certain column. In current data as you can see 'days_left' column does not have all sequential values.

```
current = {'assignment': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2], 'days_left': [1, 2, 5, 9,1, 3, 4, 8, 13]}
dfcurrent = pd.DataFrame(data=current)
dfcurrent
```

While I want to generate rows into that dataframe to create make sequential list for for 'days_left' for each 'assignment'. Please see the desidered output below:

```
   desired = {'assignment': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
           'days_left': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]}
dfdesired = pd.DataFrame(data=desired)
dfdesired
```

Note: The original data is much bigger and has other columns as well but I just simplified it for this question.

Could you please help me how I can solve this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through the rows of the current dataframe and create a new dataframe. For each *days_left* range, copy the current row to the new dataframe and update the *days_left* column value.

Try this code:

```
import pandas as pd

current = {'assignment': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2], 'days_left': [1, 2, 5, 9, 1, 3, 4, 8, 13]}
dfc = pd.DataFrame(data=current)

dfd = pd.DataFrame()  # new dataframe

for r in range(1,len(dfc)):  # start at 2nd row
   for i in range(dfc.iloc[r-1]['days_left'],dfc.iloc[r]['days_left']): # fill gap of missing numbers
      dfd = dfd.append(dfc.iloc[r]) # copy row
      dfd.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)  # prevent index duplication
      dfd.loc[len(dfd)-1, 'days_left'] = i  # update column value
   if r == len(dfc)-1 or dfc.iloc[r+1]['assignment']!=dfc.iloc[r]['assignment']:  # last entry in assignment
      dfd = dfd.append(dfc.iloc[r]) # copy row
      dfd.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)  # prevent index duplication

dfd = dfd.astype(int)  # convert all data to integers
print(dfd.to_string(index=False))
```

Output

```
 assignment  days_left
          1          1
          1          2
          1          3
          1          4
          1          5
          1          6
          1          7
          1          8
          1          9
          2          1
          2          2
          2          3
          2          4
          2          5
          2          6
          2          7
          2          8
          2          9
          2         10
          2         11
          2         12
          2         13
```

Comment: That's super useful! Thank you very much. Much appreciated!